# Best pratice to use redux-stores in Util classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cordova, react-redux

I have a utilitary class for Cordova functiosn, but in some methods I'll have do dispatch to my store.

So what's the best approach to do that?

1) Import store on my Cordova utility class

2) Pass store as argument

3) Bind my creators with bindActionCreators and pass as argument.

4) Another better option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bindActionCreators when you want to pass some action creators down to a component (or utility class in your example) that isn't aware of Redux, and you don't want to pass dispatch or the Redux store to it.

If you do not want to make your utility class aware of Redux, you could consider using bindActionCreators, otherwise options 1 could be the easier one.